# Как в MySQL слушать несколько хостов?

Tags: mysql

В MySQL есть настройка `--bind-address=IP`. В [доках](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) написано, что

> The IP address to bind to. Only one address can be selected. If this option is specified multiple times, the last address given is used.

То есть можно указать только один адрес. Есть ли способ обойти это ограничение?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно указанным вами докам, слушать можно либо все, либо один, либо ни одного адреса. Поэтому остается только возможность разрешить все адреса

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

и использовать межсетевой экран для фильтрации всех нежелательных.